# Scroll View with many labels

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a Scroll View.

I'm working with Storyboard, but when I add those several Labels to my ViewController and set the right constraints to them, it looks fine on iPhone 5s, but looks weird on iPhone 6s, because there will be too much space below the last Label.

So when I set the height of my view inside the ViewController, how should I get rid of those spaces on bigger devices?

There is probably a problem with my constraints.

My View on iPhone 5s:

[image]

My View on iPhone 6s:

[image]

Comment: You need to use autolayout to resize the content size of uiscrollview depending on screen height

Comment: Add screens from your constraints and how they look

Comment: I added top, leading and trailing constraints for each Label

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the text render size with this function:

```
//ARC code
//font: render font
//renderMaxWidth: max width of a line
//lineBreakMode: line break mode
- (CGSize) calculateLabelRenderSizeWith:(UIFont *) font renderMaxWidth:(CGFloat) width lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode) mode 
{
    CGSize availableSize = CGSizeZero;
    availableSize.width = width;
    availableSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    style.lineBreakMode = mode;

    NSStringDrawingOptions options = NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading;
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                             NSFontAttributeName: font,
                             NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style
                             };
    CGSize textNodeSize = [self boundingRectWithSize:availableSize
                                         options:options
                                      attributes:attributes
                                         context:nil].size;
    return textNodeSize;
}
```

Swift:

```
func __calculateLabelRenderSizeWith(font: UIFont, renderMaxWidth: CGFloat, lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakMode) -> CGSize
{
    var availableSize = CGSizeZero
    availableSize.width = renderMaxWidth
    availableSize.height = CGFloat.max

    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode

    let attributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: font,
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style
    ]
    let textNodeSize = boundingRectWithSize(availableSize, options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil).size
    return textNodeSize;
}
```